# A question about Omitted Variables in a regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics

I've been working through some econometrics worksheets recently. I came to a problem that I was hoping to get some help with. Assume we have a model,

```
(1)     yi = βo + β1chemi + β2disti + εi
```

and we know that

```
E[ εi | chemi, disti ] = 0.
```

Further, assume that we only have data to estimate the regression using the following model:

```
(2)     yi = βo + β1chemi + γi.
```

Then, on average, what will be the estimate of β̂1 if we exclude dist<sub>i</sub> from the regression, in terms of the parameters from model (1), and why?

Many thanks.

Comment: Google "omitted variable bias".

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one explanatory variable in the model you estimate, you have 
$\hat{\beta}_1=\hat{c}ov(y,chem)/\hat{v}ar(chem)$

According to the correct model this gives
$\hat{\beta}_1=\hat{c}ov(\beta_1 chem,chem)/\hat{v}ar(chem)+\hat{c}ov(\beta_2 dist,chem)/\hat{v}ar(chem)$

which provides the bias

$\hat{\beta}_1-\beta_1=\beta_2\hat{c}ov(dist,chem)/\hat{v}ar(chem)$

It is zero only if dist and chem are uncorrelated or $\beta_2=0.$